# Get google account name and email in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to get mobile's google account email and full name. I tried `react-native-user-identity` package but this is returning me only email id.

Answer (score 0):

try using Google firebase and follow along their authentication docs you can also use their database creation feature to store the users [firebase link](https://firebase.com/)

it works good with react-native